# MySQL JDBC SSL Client Certificates without keystore (SSLSocketFactory)

Tags: mysql, ssl, jdbc, client-certificates, sslsocketfactory

Google Cloud SQL (MySQL) supports [SSL Client Certificates](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/configure-ssl-instance) for securing connections.  I have gotten these working with the [mysql CLI client and with MySQL-python](https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/06/22/setting-up-mysql-ssl-and-secure-connections/) without any drama, but Java's JDBC driver model seems to be significantly less flexible.  I was able to get it working by importing the necessary keys and certificates into my keystore, but it does not appear that I can easily provide a specific certificate to use for a particular connection at runtime.

For my use storing all the certificates in a single keystore per JVM won't work, we have a multi-tenant environment with dozens of isolated client certificates. The PostgreSQL JDBC documentation offhandedly mentions it should be possible by implementing your own SSLSocketFactory ([source](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/ssl-factory.html)):

> Information on how to actually implement such a class is beyond the scope of this documentation. Places to look for help are the [JSSE Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html) and the source to the [NonValidatingFactory](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/master/pgjdbc/src/main/java/org/postgresql/ssl/NonValidatingFactory.java) provided by the JDBC driver.
>
> The Java SSL API is not very well known to the JDBC driver developers and we would be interested in any interesting and generally useful extensions that you have implemented using this mechanism. **Specifically it would be nice to be able to provide client certificates** to be validated by the server.

The only implementation I have seen is [GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-mysql-socket-factory](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-mysql-socket-factory/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/sql/mysql/SslSocketFactory.java) which on-the-fly queries the Google Cloud APIs to retreive emphemeral ssl client certificates.  This is what I'm starting with, but I'm disheartened by the fact some basic socket properties (notably [connectTimeout and socketTimeout](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-mysql-socket-factory/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/sql/mysql/SslSocketFactory.java#L192)) are not currently implemented.

Are there other SSLSocketFactory implementations I should be aware of? It seems like a generic implementation would be useful for multiple JDBC drivers ([MySQL connector/J](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/), [PostgreSQL pgJDBC](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc) and Oracle offer some client cert support). That way JDBC connection strings could support client certificates as standardize parameters (base64 encoded?) just as usernames and passwords are currently included.